# Write Equation of Motion in Polar Coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems

a point of mass $m$ moves on the $xy-$Plane and has the potential energy $U(x,y)=\frac{A}{2}(x^2+y^2) + B$ with $A,B > 0$ being two constants.

Let $\vec{r}$ denote the position of the mass on the $xy-$Plane.

We knoe that $m\ddot{\vec{r}}=-\nabla U(x,y)$

We first write $U(r,\varphi)=\frac{A}{2}r^2 + B$

so we get $\nabla U(r,\varphi)=\begin{pmatrix} Ar \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

We now calculate $\ddot{\vec{r}}$ in polar coordinates.

We have

$\vec{r}=r\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varphi) \\ \sin(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}$

$\dot{\vec{r}}=\dot{r}\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varphi) \\ \sin(\varphi)\end{pmatrix} + r\begin{pmatrix}-\sin(\varphi) \\ \cos(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}\dot{\varphi}$

$\ddot{\vec{r}}=\ddot{r}\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varphi) \\ \sin(\varphi)\end{pmatrix} + 2\dot{r} \begin{pmatrix}-\sin(\varphi) \\ \cos(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}\dot{\varphi} - r\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varphi) \\ \sin(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}\dot{\varphi}^2 + r\begin{pmatrix}-\sin(\varphi) \\ \cos(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}\ddot{\varphi}$

we put everything together:

$\ddot{\vec{r}}=\ddot{r}\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varphi) \\ \sin(\varphi)\end{pmatrix} + 2\dot{r} \begin{pmatrix}-\sin(\varphi) \\ \cos(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}\dot{\varphi} - r\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varphi) \\ \sin(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}\dot{\varphi}^2 + r\begin{pmatrix}-\sin(\varphi) \\ \cos(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}\ddot{\varphi}=\frac{-1}{m}\begin{pmatrix} Ar \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

(*)Since $\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varphi) \\ \sin(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}=\hat{e}_r$ and $\begin{pmatrix}-\sin(\varphi) \\ \cos(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}=\hat{e}_\varphi$ and also $\begin{pmatrix} Ar \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=Ar\hat{e}_r + 0\cdot \hat{e}_\varphi$ we get:

(**)$\begin{pmatrix}\ddot{\vec{r}}-r\dot{\varphi}^2 \\ 2\dot{r}\dot{\varphi} + r\ddot{\varphi}\end{pmatrix}=\frac{-1}{m}\begin{pmatrix} Ar \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

My lecture notes now write it down like this:

(***)$\begin{pmatrix}\ddot{\vec{r}} \\ r\ddot{\varphi}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{-Ar}{m} + r\dot{\varphi}^2\\ -2\dot{r}\dot{\varphi} \end{pmatrix}$

Question 1: Is $\begin{pmatrix}-\sin(\varphi) \\ \cos(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}=\hat{e}_\varphi$ true or is it rather $\begin{pmatrix}-\sin(\varphi) \\ \cos(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}=-\hat{e}_\varphi$?

Question 2: Is there a reason why we wrote ( ** ) as ( * ** )? Does the left side of (***) tell us something?

Question 3: Is it possible that my potential depends on $r$ and $\varphi$? And if so, could I write down the general formula like that:

$\begin{pmatrix}m\ddot{\vec{r}} \\ mr\ddot{\varphi}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} K_r(r,\varphi) + r\dot{\varphi}^2\\ K_\varphi(r,\varphi)-2m\dot{r}\dot{\varphi} \end{pmatrix}$

With $K(r,\varphi)$ being a conservative force field (so $K=-\nabla U$ applies)

Question 4: Why don't I have to transform the constants?

Comment: Note that $\vec r$ indicates that $r$ is a vector & not the radial coordinate, so writing $(\ddot{\vec r},\,r\ddot\phi)^T$ is incorrect.

Comment: Why is it incorrect? It's basically $\ddot{\vec{r}}\cdot \hat{e}_r + r\ddot{\varphi}\cdot \hat{e}_\varphi$ what's wrong with that?

Comment: It's wrong because $\ddot{\vec{r}}=(\ddot{r},\,r\ddot{\phi})^T$, so what you have written in your post is really $(\ddot{r}+r\ddot{\phi},\,r\ddot{\phi})$.

Comment: ah that's a typo yeah, shouldn't be a vector arrow there. No idea hwo you got to $(\ddot{r}+r\ddot{\varphi},r\ddot{\varphi})$ though. What basis are you using for your tuple?

Comment: @David Z I don't see why this was closed. It is one problem and all 4 questions related closely to each other. I don't get it, I didn't want to create 4 threads with the same text just to ask 4 related questions. I did read the rules and such but I have no idea what to do now. Like I have no idea what edit is wanted, how I should narrow it down - it's already answered, so I'd also destroy the answer. I'd like to imrpove the thread but I really have no idea how, I think it's formated nicely, asked nicely and all questions are closely related and non of them is really open/opinion based.

Comment: I guess you don't have to do anything, since the question is answered. But the four questions are distinct enough that they should have been posted separately. (You wouldn't have to use the same text for all four questions; you could just trim each one down to the parts that are most relevant.) I put this on hold as a signal to other people who may read this that separate questions should be asked individually.

Comment: yeah but that blocked my account (I think?). Should I now just deleted 3/4 Questions and thus also destroy some of the answers? Like I have no idea how to improve my questions to unlock the account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

It's up to you to chose a basis to your problem. They can differ only by a global fase (such a minus sign, since $e^{i\pi}=-1$).

**Question 2:**

As you might see, both expressions are the same. It's up to you chose the one you prefer. However, when you get something equals to a constant is always a good thing, since means that a quantity is conserved (in your case, $\frac{d}{dt}2\dot{r}\dot{φ}+r\ddot{φ}$)

**Question 3:**

you can get (at least, theoretically) a potential $V=V(r,\varphi)$ and there will be a general formula (take into account that $\nabla U=\frac{\partial U}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial U}{\partial \varphi}$)

Comment: I added a 4th Question. To 2: I can't see how the right side of the last equation is constant. What do you mean? 3: What? If I have a potential depending on $r$ and $\varphi$, couldn't I just do the same as I just did? I also don't get $\nabla U$. Why should that be a function to $\mathbb R$? Nabla maps to $\mathbb R^n$, no?

Comment: The RHS has one component constant (you're right, only one component is constant, not all)