# Centripetal & centrifual force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

we have a mass $m$ moving on the xy-Plane and we have the potential $U(x,y)=\frac{A}{2}(x^2+y^2) + B,\quad A,B>0$ with $A,B$ being constants.

Now at $t=0$ we have $\vec{r}=(x_0,0), \quad \vec{v}=(0,v_0)$

I further now that $\omega = \frac{v_0}{x_0}$

Now I need to calcualte the centripetal and the centrifugal force.

For the centri fugal we know that $F_{Fugal}=mr\omega^2=m\frac{v_0^2}{x_0}$

Now, the centri petal force is the force that keeps the mass on it's trajectory. Which in our case is the potential. So:

$F_{Petal} = |\nabla U(x_0,0)| = Ax_0$

Now both are correct but I'm not sure I get the physics behind it.

Question 1: Can I say that $F_{Petal}=-F_{Fugal}$ and $\vec{F}_{Petal}=-\vec{F}_{Fugal}$ is always true if we have such a problem? Like isolated and no outside forces etc.

Question 2: Does that mean that I now could derive $A$ by using $F_{Petal}=-F_{Fugal}$?

Comment: What is your reference frame? Is it body-centered or otherwise? Is it inertial or non-inertial? If it's inertial, there is no centrifugal force like what you propose.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/406076/2451

Comment: We don't really talk about reference frame yet. So I'm just a observer. Thanks though for that input, guess that'll help clear this up. Going to play around a little by looking at the problem fomr the ouside and while "sitting inside" of the mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both equations are correctly set up, yes (unless there is a calculation error somewhere), but the first one is **not** a "centrifugal force". It is **also** the centripetal force. **Both** equations are expressions of the centripetal force. So one is not equal to negative the other. They are simply straight-out equal.

---

Your first expression is derived from the (geometrically derived) relation between **centripetal** acceleration and speed in a circular motion:

$$a_{petal}=\frac{v^2}{r}=\frac{v^2}{x_0}$$

Centripetal acceleration is towards the centre of the circle path. That is the acceleration which keeps you turning. Plug this into Newton's 2nd law:

$$\sum \vec F=m \vec a_{petal}\quad\Leftrightarrow \quad\sum F=m\frac{v^2}{x_0}$$

and you will mathematically see that the total force $\sum F$ has the same direction as $a_{petal}$, since this is a direct vector relationship. The total force is thus **also** towards the centre. We thus **also** call this force **centripetal**.

The thing is that **there is no such thing as a centrifugal force**. It **does not exist**. There is a force pulling inwards into the circle, but no force pushing out. The motion has a tendency to continue straight ahead and this centripetal force pulls in it sideways and makes it turn. Turning is all that happens - no centrifugal force pushing outwards.

Comment: Ah true, that makes sense. To be able to talk about a centrifugal force I'd have to change my reference frame to the mass itself, like sitting inside of a airplane doing circles, then I'd feel a force pushing me outside, which I then'd call centrifugal force, but that's a "fictious force", right? I'm going to play around with all that, thanks!

Comment: @xotix Exactly. No such thing as centrifugal force. We can call the feeling of being swung to the sides a "centrifugal effect" , if you will. But let's not call it a force. Because it isn't. If you do observe such a thing, then your frame is not inertial, which can cause such illusions.